# Combine multiple Firestore collection in one Flatlist in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-flatlist

I have this two collection in Firestore which I would like to display in one Flatlist in React Native.

First collection looks like this: (this is created by the user)

```
collection_1 : [
    {
     id: a1b2c3,
     name: 'joe'
    }
    {
     id2: d4e5f6,
     name: 'jane'
    }
    ]
```

and second collection looks like this: (this is created by the friend user)

```
   collection_2: [
    {
     id: z9y8x7
     userId: 'a1b2c3',
     seenCount: 10,
    },
    {
     id: w7v6u5
     userId: 'd4e5f6'
     seenCount: 5,
    },
    ]
```

and I would like to display the list with the name and the seen count next to each other with the condition of the collection_1 id is the same with the collection_2 userId:

```
     joe (10)
     jane (5)
```

but currently my I only have collection_1 in my flatlist:

```
     <FlatList
        data={collection_1}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View>
               <Text>
                  {item.name}
               </Text>
            </View>
        )}
     />
```

is it possible with Flatlist? or is there a better way to this?

Comment: What have you tried to do so far? This is not a matter of displaying both lists, it's more of a matter of processing your data before you show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a new array from 2 collection lists. `data` is what you need in the below example.

```js
const collection1 = [
  {
    id: 'a1b2c3',
    name: 'joe'
  },
  {
    id: 'd4e5f6',
    name: 'jane'
  }
];

const collection2 = [
  {
    id: 'z9y8x7',
    userId: 'a1b2c3',
    seenCount: 10
  },
  {
    id: 'w7v6u5',
    userId: 'd4e5f6',
    seenCount: 5
  },
  {
    id: 'o1j3o2',
    userId: 'd4e5f6',
    seenCount: 7
  }
];

const seenCounts = {};
collection2.forEach((item) => {
  if (seenCounts[item.userId]) {
    seenCounts[item.userId] += item.seenCount;
  } else {
    seenCounts[item.userId] = item.seenCount;
  }
});

const data = collection1.map((item) => ({
  ...item,
  seenCount: seenCounts[item.id]
}));

console.log(data);
```

Comment: thanks I will let you know if this will work, I am just currently outside will be back tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

You need to combine the arrays so that your object consist of both name and screen (Please run snippet).

Then u can do it like this.

```
<FlatList
    data={final}  //this is the combined array
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View>
           <Text>
              {item.name} ({item.seenCount})
           </Text>
        </View>
    )}
 />
```

**Combine Array**

```js
let collection_1 = [{
    id: 'a1b2c3',
    name: 'joe'
  },
  {
    id: 'd4e5f6',
    name: 'jane'
  }
]


let collection_2 = [{
    id: 'z9y8x7',
    userId: 'a1b2c3',
    seenCount: 10,
  },
  {
    id: 'w7v6u5',
    userId: 'd4e5f6',
    seenCount: 5,
  }
]

let final = collection_2.map(user => {

  let name = collection_1.filter((users) => users.id === user.userId)[0].name
  return { ...user,
    name
  }


})

console.log('final', final)
```

Comment: thanks this also works, both answers worked, if it's possible to give both answers a check.

Comment: the only problem with this code is that if the user has not been seen yet or still have undefined count I get an error of undefined is not an object for only that specific user.